# Apache or PHP issue is downloading ONLY Some Pages such as index.php and some rewrite pages. Other pages work fine

Tags: php, apache, php-7, php-8, virtualmin

I use VirtualMin/Webmin (https://www.virtualmin.com/) for my hosting server. There must have been an update, but I am honestly still not sure what exactly happened, but since last few days all of a sudden I noticed index.php and other mod_rewrite pages get downloaded by browser instead of executing.

I am using mod_rewrite in htaccess, and many URLs are being rewritten. I did not write these but these came predefined by the makers of the forum software (phpBB). The weird thing is pages such as search.php, or advertise.php, or even faq.php all get rewritten and work fine. However, some pages using /viewforum.php such as /2-demerit-points/ get executed however the same script rewritten to /6-demerit-points/ gets downloaded by browser.

I have tried updating Apache to version Apache/2.4.58 and have tried all PHP versions from PHP 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, and 8.0 but same issue persists.

**Server Info:**

CentOS Linux 7.9.2009

Virtualmin version 7.9.0 Pro

PHP-FPM 7.3.33 Server
PHP-FPM 7.0.27 Server
PHP-FPM 7.4.33 Server
PHP-FPM 8.0.30 Server

Apache 2.4.58

I have tried all the AddTypes and Handlers for PHP in main httpd.conf:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

The website is: https://www.ontariohighwaytrafficact.com/

As you may see https://www.ontariohighwaytrafficact.com/index.php gets downloaded.

However, https://www.ontariohighwaytrafficact.com/index.php? or https://www.ontariohighwaytrafficact.com/? works.

**/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:**

```
    ServerName ontariohighwaytrafficact.com
    ServerAlias www.ontariohighwaytrafficact.com
    ServerAlias webmail.ontariohighwaytrafficact.com
    ServerAlias admin.ontariohighwaytrafficact.com
    ServerAlias autoconfig.ontariohighwaytrafficact.com
    ServerAlias autodiscover.ontariohighwaytrafficact.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ontariohighwaytrafficact/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/ontariohighwaytrafficact.com_error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/ontariohighwaytrafficact.com_access_log combined
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/ontariohighwaytrafficact/cgi-bin/
    ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/ontariohighwaytrafficact/cgi-bin/
    ScriptAlias /AutoDiscover/AutoDiscover.xml /home/ontariohighwaytrafficact/cgi-bin/autoconfig.cgi
    ScriptAlias /Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml /home/ontariohighwaytrafficact/cgi-bin/autoconfig.cgi
    ScriptAlias /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml /home/ontariohighwaytrafficact/cgi-bin/autoconfig.cgi
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
    ProtocolsHonorOrder Off
    H2EarlyHints on
    <Location />
        H2PushResource /assets/javascript/core.js   
        H2PushResource /styles/prosilver/theme/stylesheet.css
        H2PushResource /styles/prosilver/theme/foundation/css/foundation.min.css
        H2PushResource /ext/vse/scrollpage/styles/all/theme/scrollpage.css 
    </Location>
    <Directory /home/ontariohighwaytrafficact/public_html>
        Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
        allow from all
        AllowOverride All               Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch,FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/ontariohighwaytrafficact/cgi-bin>
        allow from all
        AllowOverride All     Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch,FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.ontariohighwaytrafficact.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://ontariohighwaytrafficact.com:20000/ [R]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.ontariohighwaytrafficact.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://ontariohighwaytrafficact.com:10000/ [R]
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/ontariohighwaytrafficact/ssl.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ontariohighwaytrafficact/ssl.key
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    <Files awstats.pl>
        AuthName "ontariohighwaytrafficact.com statistics"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /home/ontariohighwaytrafficact/.awstats-htpasswd
        require valid-user
    </Files>
    SSLCACertificateFile /home/ontariohighwaytrafficact/ssl.ca
    Redirect /mail/config-v1.1.xml /cgi-bin/autoconfig.cgi
    Redirect /.well-known/autoconfig/mail/config-v1.1.xml /cgi-bin/autoconfig.cgi
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/153206603119132.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1
    </FilesMatch>`
```

**.htaccess:**

```
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    <IfModule mime_module>
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php7 .html .phtml
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # You may need to un-comment the following lines
    # Options +FollowSymlinks
    # To make sure that rewritten dir or file (/|.html) will not load dir.php in case it exist
    # Options -MultiViews
    # REMEBER YOU ONLY NEED TO STARD MOD REWRITE ONCE
    Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Uncomment the statement below if you want to make use of
    # HTTP authentication and it does not already work.
    # This could be required if you are for example using PHP via Apache CGI.
    # RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

    # REWRITE BASE
    RewriteBase /
   
    # force https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

     RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}s ^(443(s)|[0-9]+s)$
     RewriteRule ^.*$ - [env=HttpFullProto:http%2://]
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.ontariohighwaytrafficact\.com$ [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:HttpFullProto}www.ontariohighwaytrafficact.com/$1 [B,QSA,L,R=301]

     # rewrite index.php to /
     RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [B,R=301,L]

    # DO NOT GO FURTHER IF THE REQUESTED FILE / DIR DOES EXISTS
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule . - [L]
    # FORUM INDEX REWRITERULE WOULD STAND HERE IF USED. &quot;forum&quot; REQUIRES TO BE SET AS     FORUM INDEX
    # RewriteRule ^forum\.html$ /index.php [QSA,L,NC]
    # FORUM ALL MODES
    RewriteRule ^(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)/?(page([0-9]+)\.html)?$ /viewforum.php?f=$2&start=$4 [B,QSA,L,NC]
    # TOPIC WITH VIRTUAL FOLDER ALL MODES
    RewriteRule ^(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)/(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /viewtopic.php?f=$2&t=$4&start=$6 [B,QSA,L,NC]
    # TOPIC WITHOUT FORUM ID & DELIM ALL MODES
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]*)/?(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /viewtopic.php?forum_uri=$1&t=$3&start=$5 [B,QSA,L,NC]
    # PROFILES THROUGH USERNAME
    RewriteRule ^member/([^/]+)/?$ /memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&un=$1 [B,QSA,L,NC]
    # USER MESSAGES THROUGH USERNAME
    RewriteRule ^member/([^/]+)/(topics|posts)/?(page([0-9]+)\.html)?$ /search.php?author=$1&sr=$2&start=$4 [B,QSA,L,NC]
    # GROUPS ALL MODES
    RewriteRule ^(group|[a-z0-9_-]*-g)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /memberlist.php?mode=group&g=$2&start=$4 [B,QSA,L,NC]
    # POSTS
    RewriteRule ^post([0-9]+)\.html$ /viewtopic.php?p=$1 [B,QSA,L,NC]
    # ACTIVE TOPICS
    RewriteRule ^active-topics(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=active_topics&start=$2&sr=topics [B,QSA,L,NC]
    # UNANSWERED TOPICS
    RewriteRule ^unanswered(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=unanswered&start=$2&sr=topics [B,QSA,L,NC]
    # NEW POSTS
    RewriteRule ^newposts(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=newposts&start=$2&sr=topics [B,QSA,L,NC]
    # UNREAD POSTS
    RewriteRule ^unreadposts(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=unreadposts&start=$2 [B,QSA,L,NC]
    # THE TEAM
    RewriteRule ^the-team\.html$ /memberlist.php?mode=team [B,QSA,L,NC]
    # HERE IS A GOOD PLACE TO ADD OTHER PHPBB RELATED REWRITERULES
    
    # FORUM WITHOUT ID & DELIM ALL MODES
    # THESE LINES MUST BE LOCATED AT THE END OF YOUR HTACCESS TO WORK PROPERLY
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/?(page([0-9]+)\.html)?$ /viewforum.php?forum_uri=$1&start=$3     [B,QSA,L,NC]
    # FIX RELATIVE PATHS : FILES
    RewriteRule ^(style\.php|ucp\.php|mcp\.php|faq\.php|posting\.php|download/file\.php|report\.php|adm/index\.php|cron\.php)$ /$1 [B,QSA,L,NC,R=301]
    # FIX RELATIVE PATHS : IMAGES
    RewriteRule ^(styles/.*|images/.*|assets/.*|ext/.*)$ /$1 [B,QSA,L,NC,R=301]
    #
    # The following 3 lines will rewrite URLs passed through the front controller
    # to not require app.php in the actual URL. In other words, a controller is
    # by default accessed at /app.php/my/controller, but can also be accessed at
    # /my/controller
    #
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]

    </IfModule>

    # With Apache 2.4 the &quot;Order, Deny&quot; syntax has been deprecated and moved from
    # module mod_authz_host to a new module called mod_access_compat (which may be
    # disabled) and a new &quot;Require&quot; syntax has been introduced to mod_authz_host.
    # We could just conditionally provide both versions, but unfortunately Apache
    # does not explicitly tell us its version if the module mod_version is not
    # available. In this case, we check for the availability of module
    # mod_authz_core (which should be on 2.4 or higher only) as a best guess.
    <IfModule mod_version.c>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        <Files &quot;config.php&quot;>
            Order Allow,Deny
            Deny from All
        </Files>
        <Files &quot;common.php&quot;>
            Order Allow,Deny
            Deny from All
        </Files>
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        <Files &quot;config.php&quot;>
            Require all denied
        </Files>
        <Files &quot;common.php&quot;>
            Require all denied
        </Files>
    </IfVersion>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_version.c>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        <Files &quot;config.php&quot;>
            Order Allow,Deny
            Deny from All
        </Files>
        <Files &quot;common.php&quot;>
            Order Allow,Deny
            Deny from All
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        <Files &quot;config.php&quot;>
            Require all denied
        </Files>
        <Files &quot;common.php&quot;>
            Require all denied
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
```

1. I tried updating to latest Apache version
2. I have tried all PHP versions from 7.1 - 8.0
3. I have tried all AddType and AddHandlers for PHP
4. I have checked to make sure all folder and file permissions are correct

Comment: The website loads fine here.